Manhwa/manga where a writer's creations come to life as a tower, he enters the tower and dies in order to clear a section of the tower
I'm looking for a manhwa/manga about a guy who was writing multiple manhwa/manga series. In the manhwa/manga, a tower that already existed in the world stole his work and transformed it into a real-life tower. He went to confront them and began entering the tower. I remember one scene where he had to die in order to clear a floor or section of the tower.

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent change to [edit] further discovered details in, e.g. "I'm certain that it's not The Tower Plagiarized My Pulp Novels And Might Be My Wife?!? because the magic system used Hebrew lettering for its runes, and the work was set in rural Utah."

This sounds like it might be The Heir of Mythological Heroes


Jungmin Han, "the ace of written exams," gave up on becoming an adventurer as he didn't have the talent for it. After taking some time off from the adventurer academy, he starts to write a fantasy novel. And then, one day...
[Your work has been plagiarized by the world.]
[Sole class: original author of the story.]
The novel Jungmin wrote starts to become the reality and he receives the title of the "original author of the story." Can Jungmin achieve his dream of becoming a dungeon adventurer?

Recap



Found with a search for manga author enters tower based on his creation
